# A smooth weight function of the desired property

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

Let us fix some $C>0$. 
I would like to construct a smooth weight function 
$w(x): \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ such that
it is supported on $[-1/2, 1/2]$ and $\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} |w'(x)| dx < C$
while trying to keep $\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} w(x) dx$ as large as possible.

I would appreciate any examples and references. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can take $W$ even. It is cleat that
$$
\int_0^{1/2}|w'|\ge\Bigl|\int_0^{1/2}w'\Bigr|=|w(0)|.
$$
We want then $|w(0)|<C/2$. You can choose $w$ like this. Take $a>0$ close to $1/2$ and define
$$
v(x)=\begin{cases}
1&0\le x\le a,\\
1-\dfrac{(x-a)^2}{(1/2-a)^2} & a<x<\dfrac12.
\end{cases}$$
Then take
$$w(x)=c\,v(|x|),\quad 0<c<\frac{C}{2}.$$